# Best way to store large lists in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

What is the best way to store large arrays/lists in mongodb without sacrificing query performance?

I have a large collection (>1M records) which is composed of lists. The lists each have random lengths between 0 and >40k records.

I never modify/reorder the list indices - I only add new items onto the end

When accessing the data, I need to be able to search by index/fields within a given list. For instance, I might want to run searches like this:

```
myCollection.find({list: 'awesomeList', index: {$gt: 500}})
myCollection.find({list: 'otherList', name: 'Karl'})
```

So far I've had a few ideas about a way forward:

1. Store each list item as a document with an "index" member
2. Store each list item as a document with a custom ObjectId to reflect the index
3. Store list items on the parent item in a binary tree structure (???)

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but for what it's worth, I think Redis is way more suitable for this structure. As for MongoDB, not sure. I'd try adding indexes to the list as-is, then measure performance. And then I'd compare it to the other three ideas you've had.

Comment: @Zlatko Redis is an in-memory database used for different case than mongodb in your software architecture (less persistance, less resilience, ...).

Comment: @NotBad4U Interesting comment after almost 2 years :) Anyway, Redis clusters can definitelly be fast and resilient. I know it's used for different cases than MongoDB. In this case, however, the OP is asking for a way for a fast search and retreival involoving large lists. What I proposed is an alternative approach with a technology that works much better with large lists than MongoDB. I made that comment, because the full answer would involve proper datastructures for O(1) retreivals of MongoDB ObjectIds, so it would not be Redis vs MongoDB, it would be Redis with MongoDB.

Comment: Additionally, I just saw that a `database` tag was removed yesterday. So I was originally commenting on a question that had `database` in it's tags, and Redis definitelly is a database. The fact that it's mostly used as in-memory doesn't make it less a database, it just makes it suitable for certain use cases more than for others.